# Помогите с ответом на вопрос

Tags: языкознание

Какая разница между диалектоносителем и неграмотным человеком???

Answer (score 1):

Диалектоносителем мы называем человека, который говорит на местном диалекте, распространенном  в пределах определенной территории, при этом он соблюдает местные особенности и правила произношения и грамматики. Диалектоноситель может грамотно изъясняться и на общелитературном языке, то есть владеть двумя разновидностями языка. 
В отличие от диалектоносителя, неграмотный человек нарушает языковые нормы (диалекта или общелитературного языка).

ДЛЯ СПРАВОК

Можно заметить, как меняется в зависимости от территории произношение, лексика и даже грамматика какого-либо языка, даже если сам язык считается  единым.

Самым крупным подразделением языка считается НАРЕЧИЕ. Оно объединяет группы говоров и диалектов, имеющих определенные общие черты. ДИАЛЕКТ — это разновидность языка со своим собственным словарным запасом и часто отличающимися от литературной нормы грамматическими правилами. На определенном диалекте говорят между собой люди, живущие на одной территории (чаще всего диалекты возникают в сельской среде). Если диалект — это крупное подразделение языка, то ГОВОР представляет собой своеобразную разновидность диалекта и является самой маленькой языковой единицей.

В то же время существует общелитературный язык - признанный в качестве литературной нормы; образцовый, нормативный (о лексике, стиле речи и т. п.). Например, основная закономерность развития  русской орфоэпии — устранение местных особенностей произношения, установление единых орфоэпических норм для всех носителей русского литератур­ного языка.

Можно также добавить, что за пределами местной территории тонкости диалекта будут в основном интересовать ученых-лингвистов и писателей, стремящихся отразить самобытность изображаемой жизни. Остальные люди могут и не различать диалектную и неграмотную речь.